# Authenticating Windows Domain users with Rstudio-server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, rstudio-server

this is my first time using Linux, and I'm shooting in the dark here.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and the latest version of Rstudio Server.

After much trial and error I finally managed to join my company's local domain, which enables network users to log into the Linux machine.

I have no problems logging into the Rstudio Server using a local account, but I can't log in using a network user account.

I've been on many help pages (below) but they haven't been much help:

[Password Database for RStudio Server?](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200670547-Password-Database-for-RStudio-Server-)

[NIS/AD Authentication with RStudio Server](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200663996-NIS-AD-Authentication-with-RStudio-Server)

[Deploying Rstudio Server for Classrooms](http://web.archive.org/web/20130517175104/http://support.rstudio.org/help/kb/faq/deploying-rstudio-server-for-classrooms)

[RStudio Server - Log-in and User Authentication Problems](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200717203-RStudio-Server-Log-in-and-User-Authentication-Problems)

[Accesing RStudio using domain credentials](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200662753-Accesing-RStudio-using-domain-credentials?locale=en-us)

Any help or directions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it has been a while, but I just stumbled upon your question.
Probably it not relevant any more, nevertheless, I will briefly contribute.

Since you are a first time Linux user,  I assume that you didn't make the investment of buying into the RStudio Server Professional Edition.

Active Directory user login is not available for the Open Source Edition. Only local users are allowed with the Open Source Edition.